# Django - AJAX Request returns 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am trying to simply update a boolean form value by using an ajax function to update it, because why would I want it to reload, but anyways, I have checked that I am passing the csrf_token, and made sure that's not a problem. I was thinking it was a problem with my urls.py, but I'm not sure exactly what it is.

What can I do to fix this error?

heres my views.py for the ajax form, note: project_complete is a booleanfield in my model

```
@login_required
def ProjectDetailToDoCForm(request):
    form = ProjectToDoCForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid() and request.is_ajax():
        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        ajaxVal = request.POST.get('booleanValue')
        args['doneBool'] = ajaxVal.project_complete
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(args), content_type="application/json")
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("submit", "#project_edit_date", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        updateForm();
    });

    function updateForm() {

        function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }  

        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
                    // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
                }
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'projects:todoc_form' %}",
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
            data: {booleanValue : $("#id_project_complete").val()},

            "beforeSend": function(xhr, settings) {
                console.log("Before Send");
                $.ajaxSettings.beforeSend(xhr, settings);
            },

            success: function(json){
              console.log(json);
              console.log("success");
            },

            error:function(xhr,errmsg,err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

form

```
<form action="" method="post" id="project_edit_date">{% csrf_token %}
   <label for="todoc">Task Done?</label>
   <span name="todoc" id="check_done">   {{todocform.project_complete}}</span>
   <button type="submit" id="project_edit_button">
        <span>Update</span>
   </button>
</form>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.ProjectView.as_view() , name='project'),
    url(r'^create/$', views.createproject, name='create'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.ProjectDetail.as_view(), name='indproject'),
    url(r'^view/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.ProjectDetailPublic.as_view(), name='pproject'),
    url(r'^form/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', require_POST(ProjectDetailForm.as_view()), name='indproject_form'),
    url(r'^update/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', require_POST(ProjectDetailToDoForm.as_view()), name='todo_form'),
    url(r'^complete/$', ProjectDetailToDoCForm, name='todoc_form'),
)
```

Comment: You need to post the traceback, from the console or the developer tools.

Comment: The problem is on the server side (like almost always with 500 errors). Look at this: `args['doneBool'] = ajaxVal.project_complete` where `ajaxVal = request.POST.get('booleanValue')` is probably a string, i.e. it's highly unlikely that it will have `.project_complete` attribute. That's what's throwing an exception.

Answer (score 11):

Just a general tip as you have posted all the code including HTML / JS / Python / urls.py ...

- If you have an error in your **JS** (Client side error) you will see it in the browser log (console).
- If there is an error in **urls.py** you will most likely get an **HTTP Response 404 Not Found** meaning the URL couldn't be resolved.
- If you get a **HTTP Response 500 Internal Server Error** this most certainly means you have a server error (runtime error in your python code **/views.py/**.

In general read the most frequent response codes and what they mean here [HTTP/1.1: Status Code Definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)

Comment: I had simillar problem, and you helped with some few words... Thanks!